# Tizen Studio and Vue JS: HTML Video doesn't play at the same time

Tags: vue.js, tizen, tizen-studio

I'm trying to create a Tizen Project with Vue.js. I have two videos that I want to show on TV, but when they are played, one starts after other, with just some fraction of seconds difference. How could I play both at the same time?

Here is the HTML correspondent in my Vue template:

```
<template>
  <div class="video">
    {{ msg }}
    <video id="video1" src="myvideo.mp4" width="600" height="300"></video>
    <video id="video2" src="myvideo.mp4" width="600" height="300"></video>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is where I call for the method to play video:

```
<script>
  export default {
    data(){
      return{
        msg: "Videos"
      }
    },
    async mounted(){
      var video1 = document.getElementById("video1")
      var video2 = document.getElementById("video2")

      setTimeout(() => {
        video1.play()
        video2.play()
      }, 2000)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: AFAIK, For the Tizen web, only one video tag (for media source)  is supported due to resource constraints of the devices. Wish this helps.